# Last IPs connected to in SuperPuTTY

Tags: windows-7, superputty

I have opened a couple of sessions on [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/) using

[image]

Then I closed SuperPuTTY. Is there anyway to see what was the last IPs I SShed into? (put aside the layout saving feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to see what the last IPs you SShed into in SuperPuTTY.